# JavaScript define property/method name from variable

Tags: javascript

I was wondering if is possible to define method/property name from variable.

Code

```
events: {
  'reload:clients.client' () {
    this.load()
  }
},
```

I want to replace 'reload:clients.client' with a variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```js
let name = 'reload.clients.client'

let data = {
    events: {
        [name]: () => {
            this.load()
        }
    }
}

console.log(data)
```